# Is it good approximation to use the Fermi theory in terms of proton and neutron for the given processes?

Tags: particle-physics, electroweak, effective-field-theory, fermi-energy

Suppose the processes
$$
p+\gamma \to n + \bar{l} + \nu_{l}, \quad p+\gamma \to p+\bar{\nu}_{l} + \nu_{l},
$$
where $p$ denotes a proton, $\gamma$ - a photon, $l$, $\nu_{l}$ - a lepton and corresponding neutrino. The $p-\gamma$ energy at their CM frame is of order of $10 \text{ GeV}$.

In order to calculate corresponding cross-sections, can I use the Fermi theory written in terms of the nucleons, or I need to deal with the quarks and corresponding pdf?